# How can I stop a background service in iOS after a certain period of time

Tags: ios, object, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a Cordova project using this plugin: [Cordova Plugin Background Geolocation](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation)
to get GPS updates when my app is in background.

I would like to stop getting updates after 3 minutes the app is on background.
I don't have the Objective-C skills to modify the plugin to achieve this.

I guess that there's a way to use a timer on Objective-C to stop the service after 3 minutes.

Can anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE**

The plugin has a `stop` method [here](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/blob/master/src/ios/CDVBackgroundGeoLocation.m#L197).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution, here you need to create global object of NSTimer and check whether NSTimer object is validate or not

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

if ([objTimer isValid]) {
    [objTimer invalidate];
}else{
    objTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:180 target:self selector:@selector(stopGPS:)  userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
objTimer = nil;}



- (void)stopGPS:(NSTimer *)timer {
// code for stoping GPS service.}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must modify your .plist file to indicate that you will be running tasks once the app has entered background...That being said, what you want might look something like this (all in AppDelegate)

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"Entered background");
    [self monitorLocation];
}

- (void)monitorLocation
{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:180 //That's in seconds
    target:self
    selector:@selector(stopMonitoring)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
    //Do whatever monitoring here

}

- (void)stopMonitoring
{
    //Stop monitoring location
}

 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"app will enter foreground");
    [self stopMonitoring];
}
```

Comment: OK, but how can I call the plugin method on AppDelegate?

Comment: Exactly the same way you did it elsewhere.  Namely, I assume you created an instance of CDVBackgroundGeoLocation and then called the appropriate methods on it.

Comment: I am using Cordova, so it creates a JavaScript interface to access the plugin methods.

Comment: @user1840001 NSTimer will call stopMonitor method after 180 seconds every time when app will go in background right, so just think what happened when user will go in background more than one before 180 seconds.

Comment: @Arvind I've amended my answer to handle that user behavior

Comment: @fonini I'm unfamiliar with Cordova...How did you implement it in other areas?